# Dynamically associated form fields are not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

**My problem is with the association of two dynamically added form fields**
       *I want two fields to be added with one button and field name should be two dimensional so that i can save two values @[0][0] and [0][1]*

I have used jquery for dynamic addition of the two fields but when i am added a new one it is doing some creepy thing and not giving the required result . Even the deletion is also not performing properly.

```
<div id="field">
<label>Add List Items</label><br/>
<input autocomplete="off" class="inputlist" id="listid1" name="list[0][]" type="text" placeholder="Type List Item Name" data-items="8"/><input autocomplete="off" class="inputlist" id="listid1" name="list[0][]" type="text" placeholder="Type List Item Name" data-items="8"/><button id="l1" class="btn add-more-list" type="button">+</button>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".add-more-list").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var next = 1;
        var addto = "#listid" + next;
        var addRemove = "#listid" + (next);
        next = next + 1;
        var newIn = '<input autocomplete="off" class="inputlist form-control" id="listid' + next + '" name="list['+next+'][]" type="text"><input autocomplete="off" class="inputlist form-control" id="listid' + next + '" name="list['+next+'][]" type="text">';
        var newInput = $(newIn);
        var removeBtn = '<button id="removelist' + (next - 1) + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-list" >-</button></div><div id="listid">';
        var removeButton = $(removeBtn);
        $(addto).after(newInput);
        $(addRemove).after(removeButton);
        $("#listid" + next).attr('data-source',$(addto).attr('data-source'));
        $("#countlist").val(next);  

            $('.remove-list').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
                var fieldID = "#listid" + fieldNum;
                $(this).remove();
                $(fieldID).remove();
            });
    });



});
</script>
```

i want to add two fields together dynamically and can delete them also

Comment: You can't/should not have more than 1 id for any element per page, you have multiple and are duplicating the id in the new fields so your code wont work. Also you might look in to jquery clone to add new inputs.

Comment: ok thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, It's working

```
<div id="field">
    <label>Add List Items</label><br/>
    <input autocomplete="off" class="inputlist" id="listid01" name="list[0][]" type="text" placeholder="Type List Item Name" data-items="8"/><input autocomplete="off" class="inputlist" id="listid02" name="list[0][]" type="text" placeholder="Type List Item Name" data-items="8"/><button id="removelist0" class="btn add-more-list" type="button">+</button>
</div>

<script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
            var next = 0;
                $(".add-more-list").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();        
                var addto = "#listid" + next+"2";
                var addRemove = "#listid" + next+"2";
                next = next + 1;

                var newIn = '<input autocomplete="off" class="inputlist form-control" id="listid' + next + '1" name="list['+next+'][]" type="text"><input autocomplete="off" class="inputlist form-control" id="listid' + next + '2" name="list['+next+'][]" type="text">';
                var newInput = $(newIn);
                var removeBtn = '<button id="removelist' + (next - 1) + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-list" >-</button></div><div id="listid">';
                var removeButton = $(removeBtn);

                $(addto).after(newInput);
                $(addRemove).after(removeButton);
                $("#listid" + next).attr('data-source',$(addto).attr('data-source'));
                $("#countlist").val(next);  

                $('.remove-list').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
                    var fieldID1 = "#listid" + fieldNum + "1";
                    var fieldID2 = "#listid" + fieldNum + "2";
                    $(this).remove();
                    $(fieldID1).remove();
                    $(fieldID2).remove();
                });
            });
        });         
    </script>
```

Some mistake in your code. The **id** value is wrong for all input, the input is multidimensional array. Also you can not use unique **id** for a page.